# php if else condition based on || && how to display message based on given value

Tags: php, if-statement

The $status variable can be “pending” or “approved”
How can I apply standard php if else condition with OR ( || ) AND ( && ) to display as the following

```
If the $status are **both** pending and approved:  display **pending** message
If all $status are pending: display **pending** message 
If all $status are approved: display **approved** message
```

how to display message based on given parameter using php

**for example:**

```
if(($request->is_approved ==1  && $request->is_approved ==2)){
//echo pending
}
elseif(($request->is_approved ==1  && $request->is_approved !=2)){
// echo pending
}
else(($request->is_approved !=1  && $request->is_approved ==2)){
//echo approved
}
```

Comment: What is the input? How many `$status` variables are we dealing with?

Comment: $status is a array or string ?

Comment: Hello @turaco, the next line in your edited code cannot be true at all: if(($request->is_approved ==1  && $request->is_approved ==2))

Answer (score 0):

```
//if status is array
if($status['pending'] == true && $status['approved'] == true) {
   //do something
}
else if($status['pending'] == true) {
    //do something
}
else if($status['approved'] == true) {
   //do something
}
else {
   //do something
}
```

In addition, the status can be a byte, so

```
if $status == 1 its approved,   
if $status == 2 its pending,  
if $status == 3 its approved and pending,  
if $status == 0 its not approved and not pending.
```

Comment: How can `$status` be both panding and approbed?

Comment: It's a question.
I don't know what is purpose of the code.
The code answers exactly to the question.

Comment: i have edited my code now i need like that @Michael thanks for help

Comment: @turaco , so if it helps, can you please sign the answer as the right answer? Thanks